# Dynamically generate Tasty `TestTree` from the file system

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, dynamically-generated, io-monad, hunit

I have written a file parser using the [**`Parsec`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) library. I would like to write a high-level unit test using the [**`Tasty`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty) testing framework to ensure that the parser correctly parses some given files.

I have three well formatted files in the following directory structure:

```
path/to/files -+
               |-> fileA
               |-> fileB
               |-> fileC
```

I would like to:

1. Get all files in `path/to/files`
2. Read each file's contents
3. Create a [**`testCase`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-hunit-0.9.2/docs/Test-Tasty-HUnit.html#v:testCase) for each file which ensures that the file's content is successfully parsed
4. Have this be done dynamically so I can add more files later and never change the code

I managed to construct the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns, FlexibleContexts #-}

module Test.MyParser
  ( testSuite
  ) where

import Control.Arrow              ((&&&))
import Data.Map                   (Map,fromList,toList)
import System.Directory
import System.IO.Unsafe           (unsafePerformIO) -- This is used for a hack
import Test.Tasty                 (TestTree,testGroup,withResource)
import Test.Tasty.HUnit
import Text.Parsec

-- | Determine if an Either is a Right or Left value
--   Useful for determining if a parse attempt was successful
isLeft, isRight :: Either a b  -> Bool
isLeft (Left _) = True
isLeft _        = False
isRight = not . isLeft

-- | My file parser, a Parsec monad definition
myFileParser :: Parsec s u a
myFileParser = undefined -- The parser's definition is irrelivant

-- | Gets all the given files and thier contents in the specified directory
getFileContentsInDirectory :: FilePath -> IO (Map FilePath String)
getFileContentsInDirectory path = do
    files <- filter isFile <$> getDirectoryContents path
    sequence . fromList $ (id &&& readFile) . withPath <$> files
  where
    isFile = not . all (=='.')
    withPath file = if last path /= '/'
                    then concat [path,"/",file]
                    else concat [path,    file]

-- | Reads in all files in a directory and ensures that they correctly parse
--   NOTE: Library hack :(
--   On success, no file names will be displayed.
--   On the first failure, no subsequent files will have parsing attempt tried
--   and the file path for the failed file will be displayed.

testSuite :: TestTree
testSuite = testGroup "Files that should successfully be parsed" [withResource validContents release validateFiles]
  where
    validContents = getFileContentsInDirectory "path/to/files"
    release = const $ pure ()
    parse'  :: (FilePath,String) -> Either ParseError a
    parse'  (path,content) = parse myFileParser path content
    success :: (FilePath,String) -> Assertion
    success (path,content) = assertBool path . isRight $ parse' (path,content)
    validateFiles :: IO (Map FilePath String) -> TestTree
    validateFiles !filesIO = testGroup "Valid files" [testCase "Unexpected parse errors" fileTree]
      where
        fileTree :: IO () --also an Assertion
        fileTree = do
          files <- toList <$> filesIO
          sequence_ $ success <$> files
```

This construction works, but is not ideal. This is because the output generated when the `testSuite` is run is not very descriptive.

**On success:**

```
Files that should successfully be parsed
  Valid files
    Unexpected parse errors: OK (6.54s)
```

**On failure:**

```
Files that should successfully be parsed
  Valid files
    Unexpected parse errors: FAIL (3.40s)
      path/to/files/fileB
```

This output is not ideal because it will only output the *first* file that failed to successfully be parsed rather then *all* files that failed. Also,  regardless of whether there are any failures, it also doesn't tell you which files are successfully being parsed.

*What I would like the test tree to look like is this:*

**On success:**

```
Files that should successfully be parsed
  Valid files
    "path/to/files/fileA": OK (2.34s)
    "path/to/files/fileB": OK (3.45s)
    "path/to/files/fileC": OK (4.56s)
```

**On failure:**

```
Files that should successfully be parsed
  Valid files
    "path/to/files/fileA": OK   (2.34s)
    "path/to/files/fileB": FAIL (3.45s)
    "path/to/files/fileC": FAIL (4.56s)
```

Here's my attempt to make a well formed [**`TestTree`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-0.10.1/docs/Test-Tasty-Providers.html#t:TestTree) dynamically from the file system:

```
-- | How I would like the code to work, except for the `unsafePerformIO` call
testSuite' :: TestTree
testSuite' = testGroup "Files that should successfully be parsed" [withResource validContents release validateFiles]
  where
    validContents = getFileContentsInDirectory "path/to/files"
    release = const $ pure ()
    parse'  :: (FilePath,String) -> Either ParseError a
    parse'  (path,content) = parse myFileParser path content
    success :: (FilePath,String) -> TestTree
    success (path,content) = testCase (show path) . assert . isRight $ parse' (path,content)
    validateFiles :: IO (Map FilePath String) -> TestTree
    validateFiles !filesIO = testGroup "Valid files" $ unsafePerformIO fileTree
      where
        fileTree :: IO [TestTree]
        fileTree = fmap success . toList <$> filesIO
```

As you can see, there is an unsightly [**`unsafePerformIO`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO) call in this code to extract a [**`TestTree`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-0.10.1/docs/Test-Tasty-Providers.html#t:TestTree) via `unsafePerformIO :: IO [TestTree] -> [TestTree]`. I felt compelled to use this unsafe function call because I could not figure out how to use information derived from the file system (file names) within the [**`testCase`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-hunit-0.9.2/docs/Test-Tasty-HUnit.html#v:testCase) constructions. The resulting [**`[TestTree]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-0.10.1/docs/Test-Tasty-Providers.html#t:TestTree) [was trapped](https://acm.wustl.edu/functional/io-monad.jpg) in the [**`IO`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:IO) monad.

Not only is this using this unsafe function not ideal, but it doesn't even work because the [**`IO`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:IO) action is in fact unsafe. The test suite is never run because the following exception is raised:

```
*** Exception: Unhandled resource. Probably a bug in the runner you're using.
```

Given the type signature of [**`withResource`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-0.11.0.1/docs/Test-Tasty.html#v:withResource):

```
withResource :: IO a               -- initialize the resource
             -> (a -> IO ())       -- free the resource
             -> (IO a -> TestTree) -- IO a is an action which returns the acquired resource. Despite it being an IO action, the resource it returns will be acquired only once and shared across all the tests in the tree.
             -> TestTree
```

I find it impossible to construct a function of type `IO a -> TestTree`  for the last parameter of [**`withResource`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-0.11.0.1/docs/Test-Tasty.html#v:withResource) which doesn't use the `IO a` input in the [**`TestName`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-0.11.0.1/docs/Test-Tasty.html#t:TestName) parameters of [**`testCase`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-hunit-0.9.2/docs/Test-Tasty-HUnit.html#v:testCase) or [**`testGroup`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-0.11.0.1/docs/Test-Tasty.html#v:testGroup) calls. Despite reviewing the [**`Tasty`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty) framework author's [verbose explanation](https://ro-che.info/articles/2013-12-10-tasty-resources), perhaps I am miss understanding how to [**`withResources`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-0.11.0.1/docs/Test-Tasty.html#v:withResource) is supposed to be used. Perhaps there is a better function within the Tasty framework to achieve the desired [**`TestTree`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-0.10.1/docs/Test-Tasty-Providers.html#t:TestTree)?

### ***Question:***

How can I dynamically create a [**`TestTree`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-0.10.1/docs/Test-Tasty-Providers.html#t:TestTree) from the file system which has the desired descriptive output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that you cannot construct the TestTree dynamically through resources is very much intentional. As I write [here](https://ro-che.info/articles/2013-12-29-tasty-resources-2),

> One of the major problems with tests receiving the resource value directly, as
>   in
>
> ```
> withResource
>   :: IO a
>   -> (a -> IO ())
>   -> (a -> TestTree)
>   -> TestTree
> ```
>
> ... was that the resource could be used not only in the tests themselves, but
>   to *construct* the tests, which is bad/wrong for a number of reasons. For
>   instance, we don't want to create the resources when we're not running
>   tests, but we still want to know which tests we have.

So resources shouldn't be used to construct the test tree; they are designed for a different use case.

How, then, can you construct a test tree dynamically? The trick is to realize that your `main` can be more than just `defaultMain`. Indeed, it can use the full power of IO to construct a test tree, and *then* call `defaultMain` with that dynamically constructed test tree.

So,

```
main = do
  testTree <- constructTestTree
  defaultMain testTree
```

You can see a real-world example of this in [haskell-src-ext's test
suite](https://github.com/haskell-suite/haskell-src-exts/blob/master/tests/Runner.hs#L20-L23).

Comment: While I'm *definitely not* going to do this, I could in theory require `tasty >= 0.5 && < 0.7` and use the older, less correct version of `withResource`?

Comment: Thanks for your exceptionally simple & enlightening answer. I'm going to change the structure of my testsuite to separate dynamically generated `IO TestTree`s for integration tests and the pure `TestTree`s for unit tests. I'll then graft the `TestTree`s together at the top level within `main`. Not only is that the "right way" but the tests will be better organized this way too!

Comment: In theory you could, but then you're on your own :) I'd certainly not recommend using an outdated version of tasty.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with command line options? I'd like to do something very similar, but I need to give the caller a command line `--path-to-files` option. If I write my own command line parser, it conflicts with tasty's, but can't see a way to require/access tasty Options as the test tree is being constructed in IO...

Comment: Kris, good question. You could've done it with `withResource` had I not [specifically disallowed it](https://ro-che.info/articles/2013-12-29-tasty-resources-2). Another option is to use MonadFix, although I'm not sure tasty is sufficiently lazy. But we could try to make it so. Feel free to open a feature request on github, although I can't promise a quick resolution.